# JQuery Ajax and francais encoding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, encoding

I have problem with encoding francais with jquery ajax. The response text prints somethink like s?il vou plait and it sould be s’il vous plaît and more.. I found answers here in stack overflow but either they are too old or they do not work for me. Here is the code:

```
$(function() {

    // Get the form.
    var form = $('#RegisterForm');

    // Get the messages div.
    var formmMessages = $('#register-messages');

    // Set up an event listener for the contact form.
    $(form).submit(function(e) {
        // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = $(form).serialize();
        if(registerSubmit()){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(form).attr('action'),
            data: formData

        })
        .done(function(response) {
            $(formmMessages).removeClass('error');
            $(formmMessages).addClass('succesRegister');

            if(response!="true"){
                            if(response=="Message has been sent"){
                    $(formmMessages).text("Vos renseignements ont été complétés. S’il vous plaît vérifier votre compte.");
                            }else{
                    $(formmMessages).text("Il ya eu une erreur. S’il vous plaît veuillez réessayer");
                            }
            }else{
                $(formmMessages).text("Votre courrier est opérationnel.");

            }
        })
        .fail(function(data) {          
            $(formmMessages).removeClass('error');
            $(formmMessages).addClass('successRegister');
            $(formmMessages).text("IL y a eu une erreur. Nous regrettons les inconvénients occasionnés");
        });
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: It very well could be that the response from the AJAX server is incorrectly encoded, and has nothing to do with the code you've posted.

Comment: Hello cabe_b thanks for the response. The action of the form is a register.php file with only php code in it and the html file that contains the form has utf encoding, i also trie the iso but did not work. You think you could help i post more code? Thanks!

Comment: View the php page itself in the browser it probably shows the same encoding error. Is the text from a database? Did you check the database to see if the text correctly encoded there?(phpmyadmin). This is probably a case of a mysqli query with incorrect encoding or a database with incorrect encoding.